# finding items that only belong to one set in a list of sets

Tags: python

Question: I have a list of sets, how do I find which items are unique to each set?

=====

I was playing around with nltk and was curious which words were unique to each corpus, so I made a quick script to check the symmetric difference of word sets between each corpus. That didn't work (see image) for reasons that were obvious in retrospect, but now I'm still stuck with how to find the unique items in each set?

I was surprised to not find anything like this on SO so I thought I'd post it

[image: [1]]

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.corpus import words, brown, webtext, reuters, wordnet, gutenberg

words_only_in_one_corpus = set()
for corpus in {words, brown, webtext, reuters, wordnet, gutenberg}:
    words_only_in_one_corpus ^= {word.lower() for word in set(corpus.words())}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(words_only_in_one_corpus), columns=["words"])
for corpus in {words, brown, webtext, reuters, wordnet, gutenberg}:
    corpus_name = re.findall(".*\\\\(.*?)'>", str(corpus))[-1]
    if corpus_name == "words": corpus_name = "words_corpus"

    print(corpus_name, "...")
    df[corpus_name] = df.words.isin( {word.lower() for word in set(corpus.words())} )

df
```

Comment: I think the post marked as duplicate has the best answer. Wouldn't have guessed that title though

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `Arr` is the list of sets.

```
newArr = []
for theSet in Arr:

    tempSet = ()

    for item in theSet:

        check = 1

        for anotherSet in Arr:

            if item in anotherSet and anotherSet != theSet:
                check *= 0
            elif anotherSet.count(item) > 1:
                check *= 0

        if check == 1:
            tempSet += item

    newArr.append(tempSet)
```